# HIghlight and fade effect for vue component as soon as added/refreshed

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component

How to achieve highlight effect on a vue component as soon as loaded and fade-away the effect after sometime. Maybe 5 sec later.

This behaviour can be found in stack-overflow when you post your questions or submit answer etc.

I have tried a beep effect which blinks every 500ms as shown in below vue snippet:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row" style="height:300px;" :class="{'highlightBody': highlight, 'highlightBeep': highlight && beepLight}" >
      <!-- <chart-panel></chart-panel> // Will use chart component--> 
    </div>
  </div>  
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'hightlight-div',
  data () {
    return {
      highlight: true,
      beepLight: false,
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      let ct = 0
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (ct === 10) {
          clearInterval(interval)
          interval = null
          this.highlight = false
        }
        this.beepLight = !this.beepLight
        ct++
      }, 500)
    })
  }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.highlightBody {
  background: #fffbe9 !important;
  border: 1px solid #dcc76a;
}

.highlightBeep {
  background: #F5F5F5 !important;
}
</style>
```

But i wanted effect similar to stack-over flow (fade away from Dark background to low).

I must achieve this behaviour without using Jquery.
Any suggestions will be greatly appreciative.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us a basic, minimal example with your code. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Terry i have updated my basic code. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to solve the fade away effect and also beeping effect with below snippet:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="row" :class="{'highlightBody': !beepLight, 'highlightBeep': beepLight}"  style="height:300px;" >
      Beep
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="height:300px;" :style="`background: #${highlightColor} !important;`" >
      Fede Away
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

function colorShades (color, percent) {
  var num = parseInt(color, 16)
  var amt = Math.round(2.55 * percent)
  var R = (num >> 16) + amt
  var B = (num >> 8 & 0x00FF) + amt
  var G = (num & 0x0000FF) + amt

  return (0x1000000 + (R < 255 ? R < 1 ? 0 : R : 255) * 0x10000 + (B < 255 ? B < 1 ? 0 : B : 255) * 0x100 + (G < 255 ? G < 1 ? 0 : G : 255)).toString(16).slice(1)
}

export default {
  name: 'hightlight-div',
  data () {
    return {
      beepLight: false,
      highlightColor: 'ffff94'
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      let ct = 0
      let interval = setInterval(() => {
        this.highlightColor = colorShades('ffff94', ct * 4)
        this.beepLight = !this.beepLight
        ct++
        if (ct === 10) {
          clearInterval(interval)
          interval = null
          this.highlightColor = 'ffffff'
        }
      }, 500)
    })
  }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.highlightBody {
  background: #fffbe9 !important;
  border: 1px solid #dcc76a;
}

.highlightBeep {
  background: #fffbe9 !important;
}
</style>
```

You can check out the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/todjy88m/1/)